# How to add css class dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, dotnetnuke

I am new to DotNetNuke , i am using one repeater inside that i am using div class , i am not able to reffer that class in css.its overlapping and samething is is displaying. I am struggling alot to get it,please help me out.Please find the code below

```
<div class="content-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageId") %>"> 
  <h2><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %></h2> 
  <p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Descs") %></p> 
  <h3><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %></h3> 
  <p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Descs") %></p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Provide the code so that we know what you are trying to do.

Comment: `Please find the code below`. What code below?

Comment: @Estefancy VeleZ i have pasted my code

Comment: Ive edited the code into the question for you. In future, you can edit questions to add more info if required.

Comment: That's an HTML class, not a CSS class (CSS has class selectors but not classes).

Comment: tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-3,
tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-4,
tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-5,
tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-6{
 z-index: 100;
    msfilter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    webkit-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    moz-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    o-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    ms-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, 
 [DotNetNuke.com/post](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/109/threadid/430694/scope/posts.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to display image and description using repeater template. Here is how you can do that easily, place following code in item template:

```
<div id="img<%#Eval("ImageId","img{0}") %>" class="content"> 
  <h2><%# Eval("Name") %></h2> 
  <p><%# Eval("Descs") %></p></div>
```

Comment: If i do that its taking only the last id of the image so if i click on remaining tabs its repeating same same id.actually .content id should be unique as the no tabs increase ,thn repeater content class also should be changed.see the css class below

Comment: .tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content,
.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content,
.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content,
.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content{
 z-index: 100;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -o-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
}